# Vue js 3 pass data beetwen to different pages

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I know that vue js is SPA.
But i need 2 different pages.
When you go to main page and you click on chat will open a new window with href traget blank.
Lets call it page A - Home and Page B - Chat.

When you click on showItem on the Page B - Chat it will show the item on page A and will pass some data.

Tab In chrome
http://localhost:8080/chat

```js
    ...mapGetters("PageA", ["showMessage"]),
```

Page B - Chat: I have tried VUEX and it didn't work. This code should show alert in page A.

```js
      onClickChatShowInPageA() {
      this.$store.commit("structures/setShowMessage", true);
      }
```

Page A - Home Page
Tab In chrome http://localhost:8080

```js
    showMessage() {
      alert("Got it")
    },
```

- If you trigger it from the same page it's working great

Comment: Have you tried persisting your global state (Vuex) with local storage or cookies?